# Do Dynamic Libraries (*.so) always result in a smaller binary?

Tags: c, gcc, dll, static-libraries

I've been experimenting with static and dynamic libraries using GCC on GNU/Linux. My understanding is that static libraries are directly inserted into the executable, while dynamic libraries remain separate and are loaded later. One benefit of this is that the resulting binaries end up smaller.

My problem is I'm not seeing much of a reduction in size when compiling with a dynamic library:

[image]

When compiling with the dynamic library, I expected the final binary to be closer to the size of it's corresponding object file (useStringLib.o), yet it looks almost the same size as the binary compiled with the static library.

Note: Both libstringfun.a and libstringfun.so use the same code (a bunch of custom string functions I wrote). If it isn't clear useString is the binary that calls into the libraries.

To build the files for the dynamic library I used these commands:

```
gcc -fPIC -c lib_stringfun.c

gcc lib_stringfun.o -shared -o libstringfun.so
```

To link the dynamic library with the binary I used this command:

```
gcc -o useString useStringLib.o -L. -lstringfun
```

Comment: With very small examples like this (barely 1 kB of source), the relative sizes of the resulting binaries is mostly dominated by fixed "costs", like the C runtime that needs to be linked (statically) into each executable. On my machine that's 8 kB of binary already.

Comment: Ok, that was my suspicion, but I wasn't completely sure.

Comment: I just compiled this: int main(){return 0;}

And the resulting size was +16K, so that makes sense.

Comment: That's all the things that need to happen before `main()` can run. The standard streams (`stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr`) and the call stack for `atexit` need to be initialized. Those standard streams have buffers that need to be allocated. A C program needs to keep track of opened streams, and needs to flush / close them after exit. Depending on the standard library, there might also be lookup tables for `<ctype>` and `<locale>` to be set up. The list of arguments needs to be on the stack for `argc` / `argv` to find them, and POSIX puts an array of environment variables on the stack as well.

Comment: Run `size *.o *.a *.so useString`.  That will tell you about the size of the code, the data, etc.